# In Guild Wars, how can I get an attribute of +1 +2 or +3?

Tags: guild-wars

What are the possibilities to increase an attribute of a value of

- +1 ?
- +2 ?
- +3 ?

When I read something like "Domination Magic 12 + 1 + 2" for instance, what should I do to get the +1 and +2 ?

Comment: usually 12+1+2 means 12 base stats, +1 to dom head gear, and a major rune of +2 to domination

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you see stuff like `Domination Magic 12 + 1 + 2`, the first number is the +1 attribute that you get from your piece of headgear. The second number is from the recommended equipped rune (I'm assuming you're reading build guides off of PvX wiki or somesuch). So in this case, it would be 12 points in Domination Magic, a +1 to Domination Magic headpiece, and a Major Rune of Domination Magic +2.

You can get this by applying [Runes](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Runes) to your piece of armor.

- Minor runes give +1
- Major runes give +2 and Health -35
- Superior runes give +3 and Health -75

Only the highest quality rune you have on your armor will count for the attribute. So you can't put on 3 Minor runes and get +3 to an attribute. You need to use a Superior rune for that. The hit you take to your health stacks in the same way as the +X to attributes. If you have a Superior Rune of Domination Magic and a Superior Rune of Illusion Magic on your armor, you will have -150 health.

In addition, there are [weapon](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/%22Master_of_My_Domain%22#.22Master_of_My_Domain.22) [upgrades](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Of_Mastery) you can get with a 20% chance to give you +1 in a certain attribute, as well as consumables, like [Candy Corn](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Candy_Corn), [Golden Eggs](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Golden_Egg), [Lunar Blessings](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Lunar_Blessing), and [Grails of Might](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Grail_of_Might). The weapon upgrades aren't used very often though, and Grails of Might are the only attribute-raising consumable you can reliably get year-round because it's craftable, as you can only get the others at certain times of the year during events.

Comment: you can also get weapon mods that has +1/20% chance, not to mention consummables for PVE that can also boost stats.  Also don't forget the head pieces that are +1

Comment: @yx. Yeah, I forgot the mention the weapon mods because I've never really known anyone to use them over other mods, haha. Most people would rather go for 40/40 or something.

Comment: I've seen some uses of the +1 as a weapon swap in rare circumstances to try and hit a breakpoint for a long enchantment (mostly used for pve farming) but yea, they're not that common.

Comment: Superior runes actually give -75 Health instead of -50. And Grail of Might and Lunar Blessing are 2 more options to boost attributes. Altogether you can boost attributes to 20.

Comment: @F.S. Whoops, I was apparently really tired when I posted this, haha. Fixed.